# Devolver los atributos de un array segun id

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo una lista de clientes, estoy ejecutando un servicio que por parametro le paso el id del cliente a consultar. Quisiera obtener los demas datos del cliente segun el id que le pase
Manejo esta estructura para los clientes. Intente con map, pero al imprimir en consola los vlaores imprime cualquier cosa.

```
const users =  [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
    nombre: "Michael",
    empresa: "Lawson",
    telefono: 1160005655,
    avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg",
  }]

const getUserById = (req,res)=>{

const {userId } = req.params;
const index = users.find((item)=>item.id === userId)
const cliente = users.map((cliente)=>cliente.id === userId)
if(index !==-1){
    res.send({data: users[userId-1]})
}else{
    res.status(404).send({})
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Con filter el lugar de find puedes obtener el objeto que cumpla con el parametro que le pases [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const users =  [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
    nombre: "Michael",
    empresa: "Lawson",
    telefono: 1160005655,
    avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg",
  },
   {
    id: 2,
    email: "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
    nombre: "Michael",
    empresa: "Lawson",
    telefono: 1160005655,
    avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg",
  }]
  let userId =2
  const user = users.filter(user => user.id === userId)
console.log(user)
```

Comment: Buenas, filter deberia devolverme todo el objeto de id 2?